# Displaying 24hr clock in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I was wondering, how do I show a 24hr clock in a WPF datagrid?  At the moment, the datagrid has set itself to 12 clock, using am & pm which is just plain confusing.

In the datagrid it has a simple column binding

...and I get the following

6/29/2010 10:46:42AM
6/29/2010 11:14:10PM

[alt text http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/NT6sM72khL10KZvoRPS9ww?feat=directlink](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/NT6sM72khL10KZvoRPS9ww?feat=directlink)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not positive that I understand what you are asking, but I believe you just want to change the time format in your bound data?

That's fairly easy - use StringFormat.  For example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt12Hour" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm:ss tt}}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="txt24Hour" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}" />
```

txt12Hour shows something like 05:17:27 PM
txt24Hour shows something like 17:17:27

Use any of the same formatting rules that you'd use in a ToString() call in code.  This applies not only to dates, but numbers, currencies, etc.

Comment: Awesome, I also found this after your help.  Many Thanks

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/